# Assigning text to .ListObject.DisplayName: "Error 1004: application defied or object defined error"

Tags: excel, ms-access-2007, vba

I am trying to export an Access query result to Excel.

I plan to automate the macro to run every week, so that the result should be exported to the same Excel file but different tabs named as date.

I recorded a macro. When trying to run the macro for the second time it throws below error.

> "Error 1004: application defied or object defined error"

and points to `.ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Speed.accdb_16"`

```vb
Sub Macro_Query3()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If Left(ws.Name, 8) = Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yy") Then x = x + 1
    Next
    
    Sheets.Add.Name = Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yy") & " (" & x + 1 & ")"
    
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
      "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\s" _
      , _
      "peed\Speed.accdb;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet " _
      , _
      "OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global" _
      , _
      " Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=Fal" _
      , _
      "se;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;" _
      , "Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False"), Destination:= _
      Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdTable
        .CommandText = Array("Final")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .SourceDataFile = _
          "C:\speed\Speed.accdb"
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Speed.accdb_16"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the line

```
.ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Speed.accdb_16"
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DisplayName = "Table_Speed.accdb_16"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. It still throws me the same error. When I comment that line, it works as per my requirement but I am not sure if this line can be commented for good.

Comment: What about using .Name instead of .DisplayName?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
.ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Speed.accdb_16"
```

to this:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DisplayName = "Table_Speed.accdb_sixteen"
```

I believe it doesn't like digits in value for DisplayName

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar code, and as dendarii suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514113/assigning-text-to-listobject-displayname-error-1004-application-defied-or-ob/72878930#comment27249445_18516330), I found that replacing DisplayName with just Name sorted it out.